# Existence of a certain decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I'm in the following strange situation:

$\alpha:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is a continuous, positive, decreasing function with $\int\alpha=\infty$. Let $f$ be the function $x \mapsto e^{-2x}.$

Define $k(x)=\max(f,\alpha-f)$, which is a continuous, positive function with $\int k=\infty$.

**Question:** Does there exist a *continuous*, *decreasing*, *positive*, *non-integrable* function $K$ bounded above by $k$?

After looking at some 'bad' examples of $\alpha$, it seems that $K(x):=\inf_{y\leq x}k(y)$ might work.

I'm hoping to find an idea for a proof or a way to construct a counter-example.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice $$K(x) := \inf_{y \le x} k(y)$$ is not bad: $K$ is a positive, monotonically decreasing function with $K(x) \le k(x)$. Since $$k(x) \ge \frac{f(x)}{2}+ \frac{\alpha(x)-f(x)}{2} = \frac{\alpha(x)}{2}$$
by definition and $\alpha$ is decreasing, we find that 
$$K(x) \ge \frac{\alpha(x)}{2}.$$
This implies already that $\int_0^\infty K(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = \infty$.

However, $K$ is not necessarily a continuous function. To repair this defect, we smooth $K$ as follows. Set
$$H(x) = \int_0^1 K(y+x) \, \mathrm{d} y.$$
Then $H$ is positive, $H(x) \le \int_0^1 K(x) \, \mathrm{d} y = K(x) \le k(x)$ because $K$ is decreasing and $$H(x) \ge \int_0^1 \frac{\alpha(x+y)}{2} \, \mathrm{d} y \ge \frac{\alpha(x+1)}{2}.$$
Since $\alpha$ is obviously integrable on $[0,1]$, the last inequality implies that $\int_0^\infty H(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \infty$. Moreover, we have for $x > x'$
$$ 0 \le H(x') - H(x) = - \int_{x'}^x K(y) \, \mathrm{d} y + \int_{x'+1}^{x+1} K(y) \, \mathrm{d} y \le 2 k(1) (x-x').$$
Hence $H$ is also Lipschitz-continuous.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to write $k$ as the maximum of the two functions.

Comment: I have added a complete answer.

Comment: Thank you, sir! So $\alpha/2$ is a candidate for $K$ too, right? Also, isn't $\inf k$ continuous, since $k$ is?

Comment: $k$ isn't necessarly continuous, because $\alpha$ can be non-continuous. Thus, neither $K$ is necessarly continuous. Just take $\alpha = \beta +f$ such that $\beta$ has the same properties as $\alpha$ and $\beta \ge f$. Then $k(x) = \beta(x)$ and also $k(x) = \beta(x)$. In fact, we could take $K(x) = \alpha(x)/2$ and then continue as in my answer. (Here, $K$ can be also non-continuous.)